# spservice  permission denied

Tags: 2007

I user spservice(http://spservices.codeplex.com/) function 'SPRequireUnique'.

This work fine if I access my site like 'http://abc:27236". But if I access site like 'http://192.168.10.112:27236" then I get 'Permission denied' error. Also mention I add this path in alternative path in sharepoint center administrator.
Pelase help

Comment: Is there anything in the ULS log to indicate why permission was denied?

Answer (score 1):

The Web Services use the current user's credentials. It's not clear where you are seeing 'Permission denied'. I don't think that the Web Services are going to pass that to you.

Generally the Web Services work with Windows Authentication. I haven't tried any of them with alternate authentication methods. This could be the issue if your access path using the IP isn't using Windows Auth.  I would expect that you'd see the error if you try to access the list items directly as well.

M.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the credentials for Web Service proxy before making the call to the Service's method.

```
  TodaysNewSVC.GetTodaysnewsfromInsite objGetNews = new TodaysNewSVC.GetTodaysnewsfromInsite();
  objGetNews.PreAuthenticate = true;
  objGetNews.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
  objGetNews.Url = "http://insite-dev.portal/_vti_bin/todaysnews.asmx";
  DataTable dt2 = objGetNews.getNewsFromInsite(true, true);
```